# How do I pair every two lines of a text file with Bash?

Tags: bash, sed, text-files

With a simple bash script I generate a text file with many lines like this:

```
192.168.1.1
hostname1
192.168.1.2
hostname2
192.168.1.3
hostname3
```

Now I want to reformat this file so it looks like this:

```
192.168.1.1 hostname1
192.168.1.2 hostname2
192.168.1.3 hostname3
```

How would I reformat it this way? Perhaps `sed`?

Comment: why don't you generate you file in the desirable format to begin with?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
$ sed '$!N;s/\n/ /' infile
192.168.1.1 hostname1
192.168.1.2 hostname2
192.168.1.3 hostname3
```

Comment: Would you please explain how it come to be?

Comment: @NawaMan: If you mean "how does it work?" then: If not (!) the last line ($) then append the next line (N) and replace the newline between them with a space (s/\n/ /) and repeat starting with the next line (which will be the 3rd, 5th, etc.).

Answer (score 49):

I love the simplicity of this solution

```
cat infile | paste -sd ' \n'

192.168.1.1 hostname1
192.168.1.2 hostname2
192.168.1.3 hostname3
```

or make it comma separated instead of space separated

```
cat infile | paste -sd ',\n'
```

and if your input file had a third line like timestamp

```
192.168.1.1
hostname1
14423289909
192.168.1.2
hostname2
14423289910
192.168.1.3
hostname3
14423289911
```

then the only change is to add another space in to the delimiter list

```
cat infile | paste -sd '  \n'

192.168.1.1 hostname1 14423289909
192.168.1.2 hostname2 14423289910
192.168.1.3 hostname3 14423289911
```

Comment: What if the lines themselves have spaces in them?

Comment: @MihaiDanila just tried it, works fine with no changes.

Comment: paste can read from files, you don't even need the `cat`s

Answer (score 39):

Here's a shell-only alternative:

```
while read -r first; do read second; echo "$first $second"; done < filname
```

-r - Do not allow backslashes to escape any characters

Comment: But you should [always](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/read#read_without_-r) use ``-r`` flag with ``read``.

Comment: does the `done` line need to be `done < somefile.txt` ?