# Concatenating every other line with the next

Tags: shell, sed

In a text document I want to concatenate every other line with the next. I guess sed is the thing to use? How would this be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concise and portable "join" on the Unix command-line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522851/concise-and-portable-join-on-the-unix-command-line)

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber: The question you linked is different. The OP does not wish to join *every* line.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to merge two files consistently line by line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394176/how-to-merge-two-files-consistently-line-by-line)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pair every two lines of a text file with Bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513861/how-do-i-pair-every-two-lines-of-a-text-file-with-bash)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605232/merge-two-lines-into-one

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is easiest using [`paste`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/paste/):

```
paste -s -d' \n' input.txt
```

Although there's a [Famous Sed One-Liner](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/sed-one-liners-explained-part-one/) (38) to emulate this as in [potong's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8987297/78845).

Answer (score 28):

Unless you're really insistent that it need be sed, just pipe it through

`paste -d" " - -`

Comment: Nice! The [POSIX example](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/paste.html#tag_20_89) `ls | paste - - - -` implies that this is POSIX, although I can't find the remark that says it explicitly. Note that for files, `paste a a` copies it twice, likely because two file descriptors are created, while a single descriptor is used for stdin.

Answer (score 22):

This might work for you:

```
seq 10 | sed '$!N;s/\n/ /'
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10
```

`$!` If is not the last line,
`N;` append the following line to current line, and
`s/\n/ /` replace the first (first line's) newline with a space.

Comment: Watch that last line if you have an odd number of input lines! `seq 11 | sed '$!N;s/\n/ /'`

Comment: @Johnsyweb With GNU sed this is catered for but I've amended the solution for other sed's.

Comment: Hint: In my case, the files were created under Windows, so I needed to do this (notice the additional \r): sed '$!N;s/\r\n/ /'

Comment: Can someone explain this please? Without an explanation, I have no idea how to learn how to modify this statement for different use cases.

Answer (score 3):

#### Simple `awk` solution:

```
awk '{getline b;printf("%s %s\n",$0,b)}' file
```

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] seq 11 > file
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk '{getline b;printf("%s %s\n",$0,b)}' file
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10
11
```

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by "in a text document"?  If you are editing the file with vim, you can do:

```
:g/./normal J
```