# Bash - Remove the last character of the line this before?

Tags: bash

I am trying to format a database script and I need to remove the last " , " from the lines that are before ")," but I have not been successful ...

This is the input file

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS attribute_type;
CREATE TABLE attribute_type (
  attribute_type_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  name varchar(30) COLLATE es_CO.UTF-8 NOT NULL,
  description text COLLATE es_CO.UTF-8,
  is_set smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,    <-- Here is the last character I want to remove
),


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS attribute_type_options;
CREATE TABLE attribute_type_options (
  attribute_type_options_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  person_attribute_type_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  name varchar(60) COLLATE es_CO.UTF-8 NOT NULL,
  default_value bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,    <-- Here is the last character I want to remove
),
```

This should be the output

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS attribute_type;
CREATE TABLE attribute_type (
  attribute_type_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  name varchar(30) COLLATE es_CO.UTF-8 NOT NULL,
  description text COLLATE es_CO.UTF-8,
  is_set smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL
),


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS attribute_type_options;
CREATE TABLE attribute_type_options (
  attribute_type_options_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  person_attribute_type_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  name varchar(60) COLLATE es_CO.UTF-8 NOT NULL,
  default_value bit(1) DEFAULT NULL
),
```

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605232/merge-two-lines-into-one) but it does the change in all lines , not just where I need
Thank you for your help !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
perl -0pe 's/,\s*\n\)/\n)/g' file
```

### NOTE

- `-0` permit perl to read the whole file instead of line by lines
- `-p` is like using `while (<>) {}` construct and print each lines like `sed`
- `s/,\n\)/\n)/g` is a regex substitution

### Another solution

using pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) :

```
while read line; do
    if [[ $line =~ ^\),\s* ]]; then
        echo "${lastline%,}"
    else
        echo "$lastline"
    fi

    lastline="$line"
done < file
```

Answer (score 0):

This perl command line can handle this:

```
perl -0pe 's/,(?=\n\),\n)//g' file
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS attribute_type;
CREATE TABLE attribute_type (
  attribute_type_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  name varchar(30) COLLATE es_CO.UTF-8 NOT NULL,
  description text COLLATE es_CO.UTF-8,
  is_set smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL
),


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS attribute_type_options;
CREATE TABLE attribute_type_options (
  attribute_type_options_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  person_attribute_type_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  name varchar(60) COLLATE es_CO.UTF-8 NOT NULL,
  default_value bit(1) DEFAULT NULL
),
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but just want to add to @anubhava's answer:

He suggested: `perl -0pe 's/,(?=\n\),\n)//g' file`.

I think this should be changed to `perl -0pe 's/,(?=\s*\n\),\n)//g' file` in case there is trailing whitespace.

Comment: Excellent, so just for adding an optional `\s*` in lookahead it became a correct answer where as all the 99.99% effort was mine. Do you even realize that `\s` also matches `\n`?

Comment: Hey man, I explicitly stated it was just an addition to your comment. And yes, it also matches a new line, which is completely okay.

Comment: You need 50 rep to comment on answers! I was at 49. And now he has changed the accepted answer... so there you go.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed -n 'H;${;g; s/\([^,]\),\n)/\1\n)/g;p}' file.sql
```

Comment: I have 64 tables and this solution works only for some ... I do not see the pattern to give you more details...Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

An awk version:

```
 awk '/^\),$/{a=substr(a, 0, length(a))} {print a;a=$0}END{print a}' f
```

`a` "stores" the previous line. For each line, you print the previous (`print a;`), and assign the line in `a` (`a=$0`)

But if the line consists of only `),` (`/^\),$/`) then delete the last char before doing the printing/storing (`a=substr(a, 0, length(a))`).

At the end (`END{...`) print the last line.