# Remove last character of previous line under condition

Tags: bash, perl, sed

Using bash, from the following piece of F90 code, I try to remove the last "&" if the next line begins with a "AA" (note the whitespace before AA).

```
     F = 2 * 3 * a * b * 7&
    & * 3 * b * c&
     AA = ...
```

should become

```
     F = 2 * 3 * a * b * 7&
    & * 3 * b * c
     AA = ...
```

There has been a suggestion on [Bash - Remove the last character of the line this before?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26997213/bash-remove-the-last-character-of-the-line-this-before) . 
Based on this, I tried

```
perl -0pe 's/\&\n\s*AA/\nAA/g' $MYFILE
```

and also

```
sed -i 's/\&\n\s*AA/\nAA/g' $MYFILE
```

which does not create any errors but also does not change anything. I also tried without `\s*` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using sed

Using GNU sed:

```
$ sed -z 's/&\n AA/\n AA/g' file
 F = 2 * 3 * a * b * 7&
& * 3 * b * c
 AA = ...
```

To keep this command simple, we use the `-z` option to read in the whole file at once.  (Technically, `-z` reads in NUL-separated input.  Since no valid Fortran file contains a NUL, this has the effect of reading in the whole file.)

`s/&\n AA/\n AA/g` does the substitution that we want.   Any place where the file contains `&` followed by newline followed by space followed by `AA`, this substitution removes the `&`.

Reading the whole file in at once is not a good approach if the file is too big to fit in memory.  This should not be a problem for Fortran files.

For non-GNU sed (BSD, OSX), we need to add code to replace the `-z` flag:

```
sed 'H;1h;$!d;x;  s/&\n AA/\n AA/g' file
```

#### Using awk

```
$ awk '{if (/^ AA/) sub(/[&]$/, "", last); if (NR>1) print last; last=$0} END{print last}' file
 F = 2 * 3 * a * b * 7&
& * 3 * b * c
 AA = ...
```

How it works:

This script uses one variable `last` which contains the contents of the previous line.  If the current line starts with `AA`, then we remove, if present, the final `&` from `last`.  In more detail:

- `if (/^ AA/) sub(/&$/, "", last)`

  If the current line starts with `AA`, then remove the final `&` from the previous line.
- `if (NR>1) print last`

  If we are not on the first line, then print the previous line.
- `last=$0`

  Save the current line as `last`.
- `END{print last}`

  After we reach the end of the file, print `last`.

#### Changing files in-place

With GNU sed:

```
sed -zi.bak 's/&\n AA/\n AA/g' file
```

With other sed:

```
sed -i.bak 'H;1h;$!d;x;  s/&\n AA/\n AA/g' file
```

With recent GNU awk:

```
awk -i inplace '{if (/^ AA/) sub(/&$/, "", last); if (NR>1) print last; last=$0} END{print last}' file
```

With older awk or non-GNU awk:

```
awk '{if (/^ AA/) sub(/&$/, "", last); if (NR>1) print last; last=$0} END{print last}' file >file.tmp && mv file.tmp file
```

Comment: That works perfectly fine. Many thanks for the answer and elaborate explanation! Indeed, my F90 file comprises about 10,000 lines, so the first option is less optimal; yet working! Wokred after some trial and error since I forgot the -i flag (as pointed out by ikegami).

Comment: 10,000 lines? If your lines are no more than 100 characters long, you're talking about a file no larger than 10MB. That should easily fit in memory. Might as well go with the simpler and faster version that loads the entire file into memory.

Comment: `&` isn't an RE metacharacter so it doesn't need to be inside a bracket expression `[&]`. `$1 ~ /^AA/` would be more forgiving to leading white space than `/^ AA/`.

Answer (score 3):

It becomes quite easy if you load the entire file into memory (as `-0777` causes).

```
perl -0777pe's/&(?=\n[^\S\n]*AA)//g'
```

Doing it without loading the entire file into memory is done using a sliding window.

```
perl -ne'$p=~s/&(?=\n)// if /^\s*AA/; print $p; $p=$_; END { print $p }'
```

or

```
perl -pe'print $s if !/\s*AA/; $s = s/&\n// ? $& : ""; END { print $s }'
```

All three accept any number of spaces and tabs before the `AA`.

Usage:

```
perl ... file.in >file.out    # From a file
perl ... <file.in >file.out   # From STDIN
perl -i~ ... file             # "In-place", with backup
perl -i ... file              # "In-place", without backup
```

Comment: That works just perfect. I didn't try the first option though due to memory concerns. Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 'N;s/&([^&]*\n\s*AA)/\1/;P;D' file
```

Read two lines into the pattern space (PS) and using pattern matching remove the `&` from the first line if the second line begins (less whitespace) with `AA`.

N.B. this caters for the second line also containing an `&` etc, etc...

Comment: Thank you very much. Easy to implement in just one line! Since I am quite new to Bash one also must not forget to save or rewrite the new file using e.g. the -i flag (as pointed out by ikegami).