# awk: how to append lines in a file until finding a file separator symbol?

Tags: windows, awk, gawk

Am running `GnuWin32` under `Windows 7`. Have file with this structure:

```
|<text_0>
<text_1>
<text_2>
  until
<text_16>
|<text_0>
<text_1>
<text_2>
  until
<text_12>
|<text_0>
<text_1>
<text_2>
  until
<text_31>

< more of the same >
```

There is a variable number of lines between lines that begin with the `pipe` (the separator symbol).

Desired output:

```
|<text_0><text_1><text_2>  until <text_16>
|<text_0><text_1><text_2>  until <text_12>
|<text_0><text_1><text_2>  until <text_31>
```

In Windows (therefore double quotes) have tried (from [aypal singh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605232/merge-two-lines-into-one/22277191#22277191) and [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605232/merge-two-lines-into-one/22277191?noredirect=1#comment39677347_22277191))

```
awk "{ ORS = (NR%2 ? FS : RS) } 1" < in.txt > out.txt
```

But this does not "skip" appending a line to the previous line if the line begins with a `pipe`.

How can I amend the `awk` program to append all lines to the previous line until `awk` encounters the record separator `pipe` (and continue processing until the end of the file)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can say:

```
$ awk -v RS="|" '{$1=RS$1} NF>1' a
|<text_0> <text_1> <text_2> until <text_16>
|<text_0> <text_1> <text_2> until <text_12>
|<text_0> <text_1> <text_2> until <text_31>
```

This sets the record separator to the pipe `|` and then refactors all the line with the `$1=$1` expression. But as you want a pipe in front of each line, we prepend the `RS` in this assignement. Then, we evaluate `NF>1`, so that not-empty lines are printed.

Comment: Perfect; TY. I did not know how to do the refactoring with $1=RS$1.

Comment: I like the idea and only have the nitpick that whitespaces are folded into `OFS` this way. If that's a problem, `awk -v RS=\| 'NR > 1 { gsub(/\n/, ""); print RS $0 }'` preserves them. Still, one up.

Comment: I was going to raise the same concern as @Wintermute but my solution is just to set the FS appropriately: `awk -v RS='|' -F'\n[[:space:]]*' '{$1=RS$1} NF>1' file` since that's what you REALLY want this script to do - replace all newlines followed by white space (`FS`) within records with a blank char (`OFS`).