# Removing newline character from record

Tags: unix

Below is my data , i am not able to remove newline character with sed or awk command .
When I use `tr` command, all records merge as single record and sed and awk not able to help.

Can you please let me know the command if you any one faced this type of data.

```
"2016-03-05 00:48:11|0|I|NOT SET   ||||||||||||||||2014-01-13-12.27.15.234361|2014-01-14| |0|"
"PLS RPL  2 TR-NS FATAL ERROR  |2 TR-NS FATAL ERROR                                 |TRBLRPRT|BDTRRPL|BWRINERR|0|||        ||                                                                      "
"2016-03-05 00:48:11|0|I|NOT SET   ||||||||||||||||2014-03-30-16.08.41.215789|2014-04-01| |0|"
"PLS RPLC BAD TR                 |PLS RPLC BAD TR                                       |TRBLRPRT|BDTRRPL|        |0|||        ||                                                                      "
"2016-03-05 00:48:11|0|I|NOT SET   ||||||||||||||||2014-04-08-13.32.59.536559|2014-04-09| |0|FATAL ERROR 3 PLEASE REFER"
"TO ETE|                                                       |TRBLRPRT|BDTRRPL|        |0|||        ||                                                                      "
```

Comment: This is the my record start postition 2016-03-05 00:48:11

Comment: What should be the record separator if it isn't newline? If you remove newlines, then all lines will be a single line. That's not a surprise. You can't remove newlines and expect all records to be separated by newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, but it looks like your data is split across two lines assuming every line is supposed to begin with a timestamp. This `awk` command will join the two lines together:

```
awk 'NR % 2 == 1 { prev = $0; } NR % 2 == 0 { print prev $0; }'
```

Actually [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9605559/459615) has even more concise ways of doing it with `awk` or `sed`.

Comment: Not every record is spliting only few records ae spliting into two records ,

Comment: Well you need to tell us how you're identifying when they're split if you want to unsplit them.

Comment: actually my data is having lot of reacords like above but after applying below two commads for most of the records newline and controm M characters are removed but still few of the not converting as single record
cat $f | tr -d  '^M\r'> $f.temp 

awk 'NR>1 && !/^ /{printf "\n";} {printf "%s",$0} END{print ""}' $f.temp>$f.temp2
these are the commands i am applying on my input data

Comment: they are spiling with Newline characters