# How to put two adjacent lines in the same line?

Tags: linux, shell, solaris

I have a file like this:

```
apple;banana;juice1,juice2,juice3
orange
white;black;yellow,blue
jhon;peter;lucas1,lucas2,lucas3
edward
```

I want my output like this:

```
apple;banana;juice1,juice2,juice3;orange
white;black;yellow,blue
jhon;peter;lucas1,lucas2,lucas3;edward
```

Any tips?

Comment: What have you tried so far? (people normally post their own attempts at solving the issue when asking a question)

Comment: Hello, I tried the "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605232/merge-two-lines-into-one", but it not worked for me, since some lines does not have an single word under it.

Comment: ...which you edited into your question after it was marked a duplicate. You have to expand on "file like this" to explain what it looks like exactly, which lines should be joined, and what you have tried to solve the problem yourself.