# Shell extract broken URL's

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I am new to shell scripting. I am extracting some URL's from mail via python but the URL's decoded by the script are broken. So what I thought was to write a code so that I could only extract the required URL's.

Here is the file:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988756/=
how-to-select-lines-between-two-marker-patterns-which-may-occur-multiple-times-w
.
.
.(some text)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605232/=
merge-two-lines-into-one
.
.
.
```

The output required is:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988756/how-to-select-lines-between-two-marker-patterns-which-may-occur-multiple-times-w
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605232/merge-two-lines-into-one
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried to write some code:

Comment: while IFS= read -r LINE
do

if [[ $LINE =~ ^http://stackoverflow.com.*= ]]
then
 echo $LINE >> broken_URL.txt
 echo $[LINE+1] >> broken_URL.txt
 
fi

done < file

Comment: and will later use sed 'N;s/=\n//' broken_url.txt > broken_new_url.txt

Comment: Please put your code in your original post so it retains the formatting.

Comment: As a side note, `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988756` alone is a valid URL. Whatever you write in `XXX` from `stackoverflow.com/questions/<id>/XXX` is irrelevant, all goes to ``stackoverflow.com/questions/<id>`.

Answer (score 2):

Use this `sed`:

```
sed ':loop; /^http:.*=$/{N;s/=\n//g; t loop}' file
```

**Test :**

```
$ cat file
(some text)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605232/=
merge-two-lines=
-into-one
(some text)

$ sed ':loop; /^http:.*=$/{N;s/=\n//; t loop}' file
(some text)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605232/merge-two-lines-into-one
(some text)
```

Comment: @Ritzz,Glad it worked for you. If this answer helped, consider accepting it by clicking tick mark on left side of an answer.