# File content formatting in Bash

Tags: bash

Its my first time posting in Stackoverflow, so please understand if my question is not clear.

In bash, I am trying to manipulate the file content. Essentially, I want to go from

```
AA123

AA123

BB123

BB123

CC123

CC123
```

to

```
AA123    AA123 

BB123    BB123

CC123    CC123
```

The space between duplicate words is tab delimited

Basically, unique string appears every 2n+1 line (n>=0) in the original file, and I want to move the "2n"th line to the previous line.

How can I accomplish this in Bash???

I am sorry if the description is too abstract, but please bear with me,,,

Thank you everyone

p.s. Number of unique string can be any number, but will always occur as a pair

Comment: Try using `column`. You can learn about it with `man column`.

Comment: And you want us to write the code for you?

Comment: It would be great if you can write the code for me as I am not familiar with Bash..

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/9605232/1741542, there are many answers.

Comment: Perhaps it is time to learn

Comment: @OlafDietsche Thanks!! Exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU or BSD bash:

```
printf "%s\t%s\n\n" $(< file)
```

Output:

```
AA123   AA123

BB123   BB123

CC123   CC123
```

Comment: This one doesnt work for some reason,,,  I tried using: printf "%s\t%s\n\n" test.txt, and it outputted test.txt. I'm using Centos 7 if that helps,,,

Comment: Replace `test.txt` by `$(< test.txt)`.