# How to append the data from even line to the above odd line?

Tags: python, bash, file

I have a file (data.txt) like following (with more data)

```
chr1    11106936    11107192    MTOR
    7   6   256 0.0234375
chr1    11106936    11107192    MTOR
    8   14  256 0.0546875
chr1    11106936    11107192    MTOR
    9   7   256 0.0273438
chr1    11106936    11107192    MTOR
    11  1   256 0.0039062
chr1    11106936    11107192    MTOR
    13  26  256 0.1015625
chr1    11106936    11107192    MTOR
    18  1   256 0.0039062
chr1    11106936    11107192    MTOR
    19  11  256 0.0429688
chr1    11106936    11107192    MTOR
    20  11  256 0.0429688
chr1    11106936    11107192    MTOR
    22  13  256 0.0507812
chr1    11106936    11107192    MTOR
```

I need to align data on even line number to the above odd line as follows

```
chr1    11106936    11107192    MTOR     7   6   256 0.0234375
chr1    11106936    11107192    MTOR     8   14  256 0.0546875
```

Comment: What did you try to solve this problem? Can you share the code that you are having a problem with? Would you like to solve it using `bash` or `python` or both?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Read txt:

```py
file = open('in.txt')
lines = file.readlines()
```

Seprate odd-even lines

```py
odd_lines = []
even_lines = []

for i,line in enumerate(lines):
    if i%2==0:
        even_lines.append(line.strip('\n'))
    else:
        odd_lines.append(line.strip('\n'))
```

Write output text:

```py
with open('out.txt','a') as out:
    for e,o in zip(even_lines,odd_lines):
        out.write(e+o+'\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

`cat data.txt | paste - - > output.txt`

Comment: You don't need the cat, here `paste - - < data.txt`

Comment: i tried the above code. But output is same as input

Comment: This should be the best approach. Perhaps you don't want to wrap 2 lines, but you have long lines that are wrapped or something with an `\r`. Can you check `head -2 data.txt | hexdump -c` ?

Answer (score 0):

Using a while read loop in bash.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

counter=0

while IFS= read -r line; do
  even=$((counter%2))
  if ((even)); then 
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
  else  
    printf '%s' "$line"
  fi    
  ((counter++))
done < data.txt
```

- It will be very slow on large file/data size

Answer (score 0):

Would you try the following:

```
while read -r first; do
    read -r second
    echo "$first" "$second"
done < data.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
$ awk '{
    sub(/\r$/,"")      # just in case, remove windows line-endings
    if(NR%2)           # every odd record ...
        b=$0           # buffer them 
    else               # even records ...
        print b $0     # output buffered and current record
}' file
```

Some output:

```
chr1    11106936    11107192    MTOR    7   6   256 0.0234375
chr1    11106936    11107192    MTOR    8   14  256 0.0546875
chr1    11106936    11107192    MTOR    9   7   256 0.0273438
```

Comment: isn't  `awk '{ORS=(NR % 2 == 1) ? "" :"\n"}1' <sample.txt` a bit shorter ?

Comment: @Sorin I <3 your style. Turn that to an answer.

Comment: This is a duplicate question, that answer is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22277191/939457) in a slightly different format.

Comment: @Sorin So it seems. Voting to close.

Comment: sorry for the time you spent on this. I wish people would learn searching before asking questions. I got burned several times assuming due diligence from the OP only to find out it was a duplicate.

Comment: @Sorin Meh, coding duplicates still beats sitting in this meeting. :D