# Get values from the next row and merge- awk

Tags: awk, text-processing

I have a pipe delimited file like this

```
    OLD|123432
    NEW|232322
    OLD|1234452
    NEW|232324
    OLD|656966
    NEW|232325
```

I am trying to create a new file where I am trying to merge rows based on the value in the first column (OLD/NEW). First column in the output file will have the new number and the second column will have the old number.

Output

```
232322|123432
232324|1234452
232325|656966
```

I looked at the answer here [How to merge every two lines into one from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605232/how-to-merge-every-two-lines-into-one-from-the-command-line). I know it is not the exact solution but used as a starting point.

and tried to make it work to solve this but throws syntax error.

```
awk -F "|" 'NR%2{OFS = "|" printf "%s ",$0;next;}1'
```

Comment: A `sed` one-liner could be `sed 'N;s/.*|\(.*\)\n.*|\(.*\)/\2|\1/' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `$0` will have the value of the whole line. If the field separator is a pipe, the second column is `$2` that has the number.

If you want to use the remainder with `NR%2`, another option could be storing the value of the second column in a variable, for example `v`

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} NR%2{v=$2;next;}{print $2,v}' file
```

Output

```
232322|123432
232324|1234452
232325|656966
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"} $1 == "NEW" {print $2, old} $1 == "OLD" {old = $2}' file

232322|123432
232324|1234452
232325|656966
```