# Need to read file and grab each block of text between two blank lines

Tags: bash, while-loop, scripting

Need while loop that can get each two lines and store in variable.

```
while read data; do
   echo $data
done
```

so I need to do something for each block of text which is two lines each.

Comment: Can you put your expected input, and expected output?     (the title sounds different to your details).

Comment: The output is blocks of two lines separated by blank lines.
I don't get this site formatting but basically

Each block has two lines separated by blank lines. The input and output should be the same but "read line" only grabs the first line of each block of text

Comment: it should be easy to edit now and put some sample input, and expected output.  Just replace the lines `PUT YOUR SAMPLE INPUT HERE` and `PUT YOUR EXPECTED OUTPUT HERE` with your examples (actually you might not see my edit yet .. put three back-tick characters on a line, then your code snippet, then on a new line three more.

Comment: Okay, the file reads

Comment: Okay, the file reads
```
some text here
some text here

some text here
some text here
``
I am trying to read both lines of each block of txt but.

```
while read line; do
```
Only grabs the top half of the text. I need to read both of those lines for parsing,  the parsing part I already have working fine. The blank line in between should be the sperator.

Comment: To me, the above post did not show how I wanted it. I give up

Comment: If the answer I've added doesn't help - please explain what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

For this input -

```
some text here
some text here a
some text here 2
some text here 2a
```

This will merge two lines use while read line..  It's **NOT** how I'd do it but it does what you said you wanted ...

```
last=""
while read line; do
  if [ "$last" != "" ]; then
     echo "$last$line"
     last=""
  else
     last=$line
  fi
done
if [ "$last" != "" ]; then
   echo "$last"
fi
```

This great article ([How to merge every two lines into one from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605232/how-to-merge-every-two-lines-into-one-from-the-command-line)) shows lots of different ways of merging 2 lines ..

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted. All answers were appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can read two lines in the `while` condition:

```sh
while read -r first && read -r second
do
   echo "${first} ${second}"
done
```

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I'm answering the question as written. Consider this a double vote to close if OP didn't include information about empty lines in the question.

Comment: No worries, that's why I was just asking. I think we are all shooting at a moving target...

Answer (score 0):

It would help to know what you want to do to the two lines, but you can collect each block of 2 surrounded by empty lines easy enough with `awk`, e.g.

```
awk '
    NF==0 { n=0; next } 
    n<2   { arr[++n]=$0 } 
    n==2  { printf "do to: %s & %s\n",arr[1],arr[2]; n=0 }
' file
```

or as a 1-liner:

```
awk 'NF==0{n=0;next} n<2{arr[++n]=$0} n==2{printf "do to: %s & %s\n",arr[1],arr[2]; n=0}' file
```

Where you have 3-rules, the first checks if the line is empty with `NF==0`, and if so, sets the index `n` to zero and skips to the `next` record (line). The second check is `n<2` and adds the current line to the array `arr`. The final rule where `n==2` just does whatever you need to the lines contained in `arr[1]` ane `arr[2]` and then resets the index `n` to zero.

**Example Input File**

Shamelessly borrowed from the other answer and modified (thank you), you could have:

```
$ cat file

some text here
some text here a

some text here 2
some text here 2a
```

**Example Use/Output**

Where each 2-lines separated by whitespace are collected and then output with `"do to: "` prefixed and the lines joined by `" & "`, for example purposes only:

```
$ awk 'NF==0{n=0;next} n<2{arr[++n]=$0} n==2{printf "do to: %s & %s\n",arr[1],arr[2]; n=0}' file
do to: some text here & some text here a
do to: some text here 2 & some text here 2a
```

Depending on what you need to do to the lines, `awk` may provide a very efficient solution. (as may `sed`)