# How to merge two files consistently line by line

Tags: language-agnostic

I have two files (**file1.txt** & **file2.txt** ). The files are only examples.

How can I merge the two files, in order to create the file - **merge_files.txt** as example 3?

I am now writing a [KornShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KornShell) (`ksh`) script, so merge can be done with KornShell, [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK), [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed), a [Perl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) one-liner, etc.

Background - why I need to merge the files: my target is to rename the *old* file (exist in first field) to a *new* file (exist in the second field).

### Example 1

#### File *file1.txt*

```
/etc/port1-192.9.200.1-255.555.255.0
/etc/port2-192.9.200.1-255.555.255.0
/etc/port3-192.9.200.1-255.555.255.0
/etc/port4-192.9.200.1-255.555.255.0
/etc/port5-192.9.200.1-255.555.255.0
.
.
.
.
```

### Example 2

#### File *file2.txt*

```
/etc/port1-192.90.2.1-255.555.0.0
/etc/port2-192.90.2.1-255.555.0.0
/etc/port3-192.90.2.1-255.555.0.0
/etc/port4-192.90.2.1-255.555.0.0
/etc/port5-192.90.2.1-255.555.0.0
.
.
.
.
```

### Example 3

#### File *merge_files.txt*

```
/etc/port1-192.9.200.1-255.555.255.0  /etc/port1-192.90.2.1-255.555.0.0
/etc/port2-192.9.200.1-255.555.255.0  /etc/port2-192.90.2.1-255.555.0.0
/etc/port3-192.9.200.1-255.555.255.0  /etc/port3-192.90.2.1-255.555.0.0
/etc/port4-192.9.200.1-255.555.255.0  /etc/port4-192.90.2.1-255.555.0.0
/etc/port5-192.9.200.1-255.555.255.0  /etc/port5-192.90.2.1-255.555.0.0
.
.
.
.
.
```

### Example 4 (merge_files.txt structure)

```
first field                           second field

OLD file                              NEW file
```

Comment: Are the two files always the same length? (your final goal is only to rename files, and you will delete the `merge_files.txt` after renaming the files?)

Comment: No this is only example ( length or PATH can be more diffrent ) and file content may be diff also ( no need to delete the merge_files.txt )

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You can use `paste` to format the files side by side:

```
$ paste -d" " file1.txt file2.txt
/etc/port1-192.9.200.1-255.555.255.0 /etc/port1-192.90.2.1-255.555.0.0
/etc/port2-192.9.200.1-255.555.255.0 /etc/port2-192.90.2.1-255.555.0.0
/etc/port3-192.9.200.1-255.555.255.0 /etc/port3-192.90.2.1-255.555.0.0
/etc/port4-192.9.200.1-255.555.255.0 /etc/port4-192.90.2.1-255.555.0.0
/etc/port5-192.9.200.1-255.555.255.0 /etc/port5-192.90.2.1-255.555.0.0
```

E.g.:

```
$ paste -d" " file1.txt file2.txt | while read from to; do echo mv "${from}" "${to}"; done
mv /etc/port1-192.9.200.1-255.555.255.0 /etc/port1-192.90.2.1-255.555.0.0
mv /etc/port2-192.9.200.1-255.555.255.0 /etc/port2-192.90.2.1-255.555.0.0
mv /etc/port3-192.9.200.1-255.555.255.0 /etc/port3-192.90.2.1-255.555.0.0
mv /etc/port4-192.9.200.1-255.555.255.0 /etc/port4-192.90.2.1-255.555.0.0
mv /etc/port5-192.9.200.1-255.555.255.0 /etc/port5-192.90.2.1-255.555.0.0
```

Of course you would want to throw in some safety checks (`[ -f "${from}" ]`, ...).

Disclaimer: Works only if there are no spaces in your filenames.

Comment: paste command defined in linux and solaris ? , because my script will run on both OS ( linux & solaris )

Comment: `paste` is available on any [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/utilities/paste.html)-compliant system and both Linux and Solaris ship with it ([here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5165/6mbb0m9n5/index.html) is the Solaris man page on Oracle's website), so this is a portable solution.

Comment: How can I paste the files side by side, without the space in between? 
i.e., use `paste -d" " file1.txt file2.txt` - without the space delimiter? - Thanks in advance!

Comment: @VikasGoel `paste -d'\0'` (see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/paste.html#tag_20_89_16).

Comment: Is there a batch (Windows) equivalent method?

Answer (score 4):

This Perl one-liner will display the necessary renames:

```
perl -e 'open $f[$_-1], "file$_.txt" for 1,2; print "rename @n\n" while chomp(@n = map ''.<$_>, @f)'
```

If this works for you then replace the `print` statement with a real rename and use

```
perl -e 'open $f[$_-1], "file$_.txt" for 1,2; rename @n while chomp(@n = map ''.<$_>, @f)'
```

to do the actual renaming.

Answer (score 4):

```
paste -d " " file1.txt file2.txt
```

works great for this job.

But in case you are handling text files in a Windows environment and make use of GNU [paste](http://linux.die.net/man/1/paste), make sure to transform the files to Unix format (CR) and do not use files with (CR-LF).

GNU paste does not seem to handle DOS formats properly and parsing is unpredictable. The expected output is erratic and unexpected without warnings.

You may use [gVim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29#Interface) to transform them easily (menu *Edit* → *File Settings* → *File Format*).

Comment: Is there a batch (Windows) equivalent method?

Answer (score 0):

Completely unrelated ways to achieve the OP's goal of renaming numbered files:

```
for f in {1..5}; do mv /etc/port$d-192.9.200.1-255.555.255.0 /etc/port$d-192.90.2.1-255.555.0.0; done
```

Another possibility based on `rename`

```
rename 's/192.9.200.1/192.90.2.1/' /etc/port[1-5]-192.9.200.1-255.555.255.0
```

Comment: Question is to merge file contents, not rename

Answer (score 0):

#### Command

```
paste file1 file2
```

#### Output

```
/etc/port1-192.9.200.1-255.555.255.0    /etc/port1-192.90.2.1-255.555.0.0
/etc/port2-192.9.200.1-255.555.255.0    /etc/port2-192.90.2.1-255.555.0.0
/etc/port3-192.9.200.1-255.555.255.0    /etc/port3-192.90.2.1-255.555.0.0
/etc/port4-192.9.200.1-255.555.255.0    /etc/port4-192.90.2.1-255.555.0.0
/etc/port5-192.9.200.1-255.555.255.0    /etc/port5-192.90.2.1-255.555.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's sample code to merge files in Windows [CMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe):

```
: Count number of lines to merge
for /f "tokens=*" %i in ('find /c /v "" ^< test2.txt') do set /a n=%i<nul

: Read 2 files & merge line by line
for /l %a in (1,1,%n%) do (
for /f "tokens=*" %i in ('find /v /n "" ^< test1.txt ^| find "[%a]"') do (
for /f "tokens=*" %j in ('find /v /n "" ^< test2.txt ^| find "[%a]"') do (
set a=%i
set b=%j
set a=!a:*]=!
set b=!b:*]=!
echo:!a! -- !b!
)))
```

Comment: Doesn't it work with indentation?