# combining multiple csv file

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have 3 csv files and I want to write these 3 file into a single csv file how it will possible.
for example

### file1.csv

```
a b c d
1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8
```

### file 2.csv

```
e f g h
13 14 15 16
17 18 19 20
```

### file3.csv

```
i j k l 
9 10 11 12 
21 22 23 24
```

The required output will be as follows

```
  a b c d e   f g  h  i j  k  l
  1 2 3 4 13 14 15 16 9 10 11 12
  5 6 7 8 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
```

Comment: `can anyone provide python code` - Whoa, no. This is stackoverlow.com, not domyworkforyou.com . Show us your code, we will gladly help you with it.

Comment: Please read some Python tutorial about file processing, then. You can start [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm). To understand the basics, you'll need to learn. You aren't getting anywhere by asking for code.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), a data manipulate tool.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')
df3 = pd.read_csv('file3.csv')

df_combined = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3],axis=1)
df_combined.to_csv('output.csv', index=None)
```

Then you get the combined csv file `output.csv`

Answer (score 1):

The guys are right, you should not ask for code.  Nevertheless I found the task compelling enough to invest the three minutes to hack down this:

```
import csv

allColumns = []
for dataFileName in [ 'a.csv', 'b.csv', 'c.csv' ]:
  with open(dataFileName) as dataFile:
    fileColumns = zip(*list(csv.reader(dataFile, delimiter=' ')))
    allColumns += fileColumns

allRows = zip(*allColumns)

with open('combined.csv', 'w') as resultFile:
  writer = csv.writer(resultFile, delimiter=' ')
  for row in allRows:
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Note that this solution might not work properly for large input.  It also assumes that all files have an equal amount of rows (lines) and might break if this is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

#### Python Pandas way.

(slightly improved version of above-posted code)

```
import pandas as pd

files = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file3.csv']

df_combined = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, files))
df_combined.to_csv('output.csv', index=None)
```

Then you get the combined csv file `output.csv`

#### Unix Command Line way.

```
paste -d" " file1.txt file2.txt
```

If you are using UNIX type OS, please check if you care just about merging files [how to merge two files consistently line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394176/how-to-merge-two-files-consistently-line-by-line)

Godspeed.

Answer (score 0):

An idea could be to use the zip function

```
file1 = "a b c d\n1 2 3 4\n5 6 7 8"
file2 = "e f g h\n13 14 15 16\n17 18 19 20"
file3 = "i j k l\n9 10 11 12\n21 22 23 24"

merged_file =[i+" " +j+" " +k for i,j,k in zip(file1.split('\n'),file2.split('\n'),file3.split('\n'))]
for i in merged_file:
   print i
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering all files have equal lines. This solution will work fine for large inputs as well, as only just 3 lines(one from each file) are brought into memory at once.

```
import csv
with open('foo1.txt') as f1, open('foo2.txt') as f2, \
     open('foo2.txt') as f3, open('out.txt', 'w') as f_out:

     writer = csv.writer(f_out, delimiter=' ')
     readers = [csv.reader(x, delimiter=' ') for x in (f1, f2, f3)]
     while True:
         try:
             writer.writerow([y for w in readers for y in next(w)])
         except StopIteration:
             break
```

A for-loop based version of the above code, but this requires iteration over one of the files first to get the line count:

```
import csv
with open('foo1.txt') as f1, open('foo2.txt') as f2, \
     open('foo2.txt') as f3, open('out.txt', 'w') as f_out:

     writer = csv.writer(f_out, delimiter=' ')
     lines = sum(1 for _ in f1) #Number of lines in f1
     f1.seek(0)                 #Move the file pointer to the start of file 
     readers = [csv.reader(x, delimiter=' ') for x in (f1, f2, f3)]
     for _ in range(lines):
         writer.writerow([y for w in readers for y in next(w)])
```

Comment: It includes a extra new line, open the `out.txt` as `wb`.

Comment: @thefourtheye Are you sure? There's no extra new line, tested on both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: I tried on Python 2 and I got one extra new line, so Jon suggested to use `wb` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
inputs = 'file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file3.csv'

with open('out.csv','w') as output:
    for line in zip(*map(open, inputs)):
        output.write('%s\n'%' '.join(i.strip() for i in line))
```

EDIT :
Here's a detailed version.

```
inputs = 'file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file3.csv'

# open all input files
inputs = map(open, inputs)

with open('out.csv','w') as output:

    # iter over all the input files at the same time
    for line in zip(*inputs):

        # format the output line from input lines
        line = ' '.join(i.strip() for i in line)

        output.write('%s\n' % line)
```

Comment: Provide some more detail please.

Answer (score 0):

Further to the first answer, which is the right answer, you can make it a bit more general to deal with any number of csv files in a folder by:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

folder = r"C:\MyFolder"

frames = [pd.read_csv(os.path.join(folder,name) for name in os.listdir(folder) if name.endswith('.csv')]

merged = pd.concat(frames)
```

Documentation:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/merging.html

Answer (score 0):

Using the pandas module came to mind first, as in waitingkuo's answer. But I guess you could use DictWriter too...

```
import csv

# Initialize output file
header = [x for x in 'abcdefghijkl']    
output = csv.DictWriter(open('final_output.csv', 'wb'), fieldnames = header)
output.writerow(dict(zip(header, header))) 

# Compile contents of all three files into a single dictionary, outputdict
outputdict = {key:[] for key in header}
for fname in ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file3.csv']: 
    f = csv.DictReader(open(fname, 'r')) 
   [(outputdict[k]).append(line[k]) for k in line for line in f]


# Transfer the contents of outputdict into a csv file
[output.writerow(l) for l in outputdict]
```