# Merge csv files with same name from multiple subfolders

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have csv files in folders i want to read and merge these files in one csv.

folder A have 2 subfolders B and C , and B and C have other subfolders and csv files are in last subfolders .

here is folders diagram:
[image]

Comment: Perhaps this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21040578/combining-multiple-csv-file

Comment: @mzze its just about simple combine of csv files , my problems is how to read and merge csv files from inside of multiple subfolders , 3 layers of folders and and csv file is in 3rd layer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `os.walk`. `os.walk` gives you a list of tuples, with the last one part of the tuple representing all the filenames in the current directory.

```
import os
path = os.path.join('path', 'to', 'directory')
files = [os.path.join(path,file) for dir, dir_name, file_list in os.walk(path) for file in file_list]
```

that convoluted list comprehension is basically just:

```
# unpack the tuple into dir, dir_name, file_list

files = []
for dir, dir_name, file_list in os.walk(path):
    for file in file_list:
        files.append(os.path.join(path,file))
```

and then just use `pd.concat` like so

```
import pandas as pd

combined_df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file) for file in files])
```

Comment: path = os.path.join('path', 'to', 'directory')    , i need to change path and directory ?

Comment: just insert the directory separated by comma like `os.path.join('C', 'Users','Documents','Projects')`. `os.path.join` will create a path that the system will understand (which changes beside on what OS you have)

Comment: after append 'files' only have list of names of all csv files. but when try pd.concat its give error ,EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file

Comment: well, `EmptyDataError` means the csv doesn't contain any data inside

Comment: all files have data. this code is only reading file names not reading file data

Comment: @Nickel. I think I know what the issue is. Edited

Answer (score 2):

You can use `glob` and `pandas.concat`.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

files = glob.glob("A/*/*/*.csv")
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in files])

df.to_csv("merged.csv")
```