# XMLStarlet: concatenate node values from different parents based on positional index

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, xmlstarlet

I am trying to parse XML files and generate a CSV of certain values. Here is an example XML file:
http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=31.7815&lon=-84.3711&FcstType=digitalDWML

The XML file has two different node types that I am interested in.

1. The `start-valid-time` nodes (`//start-valid-time`)
2. The `coverage` attribute of `value` nodes that don't have an `additional` attribute (`//weather-conditions/value[not(@additive)]/@coverage`) .

The nodes are linked together not by nesting but by position. 
The first `start-valid-time` node corresponds to the first `//weather-conditions/value[not@additive)]/@coverage` attribute.

I would like to output the `start-valid-time` followed by a comma followed by the corresponding `coverage` attribute.
e.g

`2015-03-11T14:00:00-04:00, chance
2015-03-11T15:00:00-04:00, chance
...
2015-03-12T03:00:00-04:00, slight chance`

I have been attempting various `xmlstarlet` commands to no avail.

Here's one:

```
xmlstarlet sel -T  -t -m "//weather-conditions/value[not(@additive)]" -v "//start-valid-time" -v "@coverage" -n  XML
```

Perhaps I got closest with this command:

```
xmlstarlet sel -T  -t -m "//start-valid-time" -v "concat(current(),',',//weather-conditions[count(preceding-sibling::start-valid-time)+1]/value/@coverage)" -n XML
```

However the values of the `coverage` attribute seem to all be from its first instance.

I'd appreciate some help with this one!

Comment: That link leads nowhere, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Odd - it worked a second ago. I updated it.. now it works again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very tough call in XPath alone, but it's dead-simple in XSLT.

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

  <xsl:variable name="weatherCond" select="//weather-conditions/value[not(@additive)]" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//start-valid-time">
      <xsl:variable name="myPos" select="position()" />
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="$weatherCond[position() = $myPos]/@coverage" />
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;'" />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

outputs

```
2015-03-11T17:00:00-04:00,chance
2015-03-11T18:00:00-04:00,chance
2015-03-11T19:00:00-04:00,chance
2015-03-11T20:00:00-04:00,chance
2015-03-11T21:00:00-04:00,chance
2015-03-11T22:00:00-04:00,chance
2015-03-11T23:00:00-04:00,chance
2015-03-12T00:00:00-04:00,chance
2015-03-12T01:00:00-04:00,chance
2015-03-12T02:00:00-04:00,slight chance
2015-03-12T03:00:00-04:00,slight chance
2015-03-12T04:00:00-04:00,slight chance
...
```

That said, I suppose you could also simply use two basic xmlstarlet select commands and [join their outputs line-wise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16394515/18771).

Comment: This is excellent. How would I change @coverage to concat both values nodes (if the one containing the additive parameter exists)?

Comment: If there can only be one additive parameter per value, just use `<xsl:if test="following-sibling::value[1][@additive]">` to check for it and then output it with `<xsl:value-of>` inside the `if`. If there can be more, things get a little more complex.

Comment: An equivalent xmlstarlet command should be `xmlstarlet sel -T -t --var 'weatherCond=//weather-conditions/value[not(@additive)]' -m //start-valid-time --var 'myPos=position()' -v . -o , -v '$weatherCond[position() = $myPos]/@coverage' -n`, substitute `"` for `'` if using `cmd.exe`.

Comment: @npostavs I didn't realize that `$weatherCond[position() = $myPos]` is what I needed and not `$weatherCond[position()]` . I had a feeling you'd need to store temporary variables. Thank you!