# For loop with multiple varibles(statements)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, for-loop

I'm looking to automate dns-add by creating two `for` loop variables. I'm not sure how this is possible. I know my code below is wrong. I'm having difficulties understanding how to create two variables in a one-liner.

```
for i in `cat list.csv`;
  for g in `cat list2.csv`; do
    echo $i;
    echo $g;
    dns-add-record --zone=impl.wd2.wd --record=$i --type=CNAME --record-value=$g
  done;
done
```

The only thing i thought might work was this, but I doubt it'll work. Does anyone have any hints?

```
for i in `cat list.csv` && \
  for g in `cat list2.csv ; do
    echo $i && $g;
    dns-add-record --zone=impl.wd2.wd --record=$i --type=CNAME --record-value=$g
  done;
done
```

Comment: Take a look at this. It's not a general answer to your question but might fit your use-case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394176/how-to-merge-two-files-consistently-line-by-line

Answer (score 7):

A `for` loop is the wrong construct for iterating over *any* file (see [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)), let alone two files. Use a while loop with the `read` command instead.

```
while read -u 3 i; read -u 4 g; do
    echo "$i"
    echo "$g"
    dns-add-record --zone=impl.wd2.wd --record="$i" --type=CNAME --record-value="$g"
done 3< list.csv 4< list2.csv
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response i really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing one `do` ?

```
for i in `cat list.csv`; **do** 
  for g in `cat list2.csv`; do
    echo $i;
    echo $g;
    dns-add-record --zone=impl.wd2.wd --record=$i --type=CNAME --record- value=$g
done; done
```