# Adding contents of Files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm new in shell/Linux and I was wondering if it was possible to use CAT or AWK to append two files together without having them put the text below, this being:

```
text1
text2
```

Let's take file1 and file2, both .txt.

file1.txt

```
I hold some info
I have other info
I like code
```

file2.txt

```
that is sensible
that isn't sensible
& I like coffee
```

Now, what I wish to know is if it's possible to take file2.txt and append it to file1.txt and make them into something like this:

```
I hold some info that is sensible
I have other info that isn't sensible
I like code & I like coffee
```

my current code is:

```
    #!/bin/bash
cat /etc/passwd | grep ^a | tail -n +3 | head | cut -d':' -f1,5  | cut -c 2- | sed 's/:/;/g; s/,/;/g' | sed 's/$/a/g' > aux.txt
cat aux.txt | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,9}' | sed 's/$/@iscte-iul.pt;100/g' > aux1.txt
cat aux.txt aux1.txt | cut -f1-7 > aux.txt
cat aux.txt > pacientes.txt
rm aux.txt | rm  aux1.txt
```

Comment: [how to merge two files consistently line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394176/how-to-merge-two-files-consistently-line-by-line)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `paste`:

```
$ paste -d ' ' file1.txt file2.txt
I hold some info that is sensible
I have other info that isn't sensible
I like code & I like coffee
```

Comment: Wow, how I was looking for a paste and forgot about the original Paste... Thank you very much haha