# How to parse tab-delimited data (of different formats) into a data.table/data.frame?

Tags: r, parsing, data.table, csv

I am trying to parse tab-delimited data, which has been saved as a text file with extraneous data. I would like this to be an R data.table/data.frame.

The tab-delimited format is the following:

```
A   1092    -   1093    +   1X
B   1093    HRDCPMRFYT
A   1093    +   1094    -   1X
B   1094    BSZSDFJRVF
A   1094    +   1095    +   1X
B   1095    SSTFCLEPVV
...
```

There are only two types of rows, A and B. A consistently has 5 columns, e.g. for the first row,

```
1092    -   1093    +   1X
```

B consistently has two columns:

```
1093    HRDCPMRFYT
```

Question: How do you parse a file with "alternating" rows with different formats?

Let's say that this was a text file which was only of this format, alternating rows of A and B, with 5 columns and 2 columns respectively. How do you parse this into an R data.table? My idea how be to create the following format:

```
1092    -    1093    +    1X    1093    HRDCPMRFYT
1093    +    1094    -    1X    1094    BSZSDFJRVF
1094    +    1095    +    1X    1095    SSTFCLEPVV
...
```

Comment: just to confirm: you are wanting to append the even rows to the odd (are they always alternating?), to create seven columns?

Comment: @user20650 Yes, that's the preferable way to do this. If it's easier to create two data.tables, "A" and "B", that would be useful too I think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to go is to read in your data with `readLines`, pull out the bits you want, and pass to `read.table` to form the dataframe. So if the rows are alternating then:

```
txt <- 
'1092    -   1093    +   1X
1093    HRDCPMRFYT
1093    +   1094    -   1X
1094    BSZSDFJRVF
1094    +   1095    +   1X
1095    SSTFCLEPVV'


rd <- readLines(textConnection(txt))
data.frame(read.table(text=rd[c(TRUE, FALSE)]), 
           read.table(text=rd[c(FALSE, TRUE)]))
```

Change `textConnection(txt)` to your file path

---

Another way is to read in only once and then post-process

```
r <- read.table(text=txt, fill=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, na.strings = "")
d <- cbind(r[c(TRUE, FALSE),], r[c(FALSE, TRUE),])
d[ colSums(is.na(d)) < nrow(d)]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can run shell commands using `fread`. In Win10, you can even run some linux utilities such as `sed`

Hence, you can simply do

```
fread("sed '$!N;s/\\n/ /' test.tab")
#      V1 V2   V3 V4      V5         V6
# 1: 1092  - 1093  + 1X 1093 HRDCPMRFYT
# 2: 1093  + 1094  - 1X 1094 BSZSDFJRVF
# 3: 1094  + 1095  + 1X 1095 SSTFCLEPVV
```

(sed syntax taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8987297/3001626))

---

Data

```
text <- "1092    -   1093    +   1X
1093    HRDCPMRFYT
1093    +   1094    -   1X
1094    BSZSDFJRVF
1094    +   1095    +   1X
1095    SSTFCLEPVV"

# Saving it as tab separated file on disk
write(gsub(" +", "\t", text), file = "test.tab")
```