# How to exclude certain lines when parsing tab-delimited data into an R data.table/data.frame?

Tags: r, parsing, data.table, csv

This question is related to the following question:

[How to parse tab-delimited data (of different formats) into a data.table/data.frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315948/how-to-parse-tab-delimited-data-of-different-formats-into-an-r-data-table-data)

I have a text file which is malformed, whereby he tab-delimited format is the following:

```
A   1092    -   1093    +   1X
B   1093    HRDCPMRFYT
A   1093    +   1094    -   1X
B   1094    BSZSDFJRVF
A   1094    +   1095    +   1X
B   1095    SSTFCLEPVV
...
```

However, there are several *long* lines in the text file which are technically tab-delimited, but are long strings. e.g. the rows 'Z' and 'Y' here

```
Z  FX:E:4.2
Y   23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M 
A   1092    -   1093    +   1X
B   1093    HRDCPMRFYT
A   1093    +   1094    -   1X
B   1094    BSZSDFJRVF
A   1094    +   1095    +   1X
B   1095    SSTFCLEPVV
...
```

There is a section of this text file whereby `Y   23434M,23434M,...` is possibly several GB long.

These lines are exceptionally rare, and are only labeled by a preceding `Z` or `Y`. I've currently opened up the file within a text editor and deleted these lines.

However, this is not algorithmically reasonable. Is there a way to parse this file such that either (1) only rows `A` and `B` are used or (2) rows `Z` and `Y` are explicitly not used?

EDIT: To clarify, Z is *not* a long string. Only 'Y' is a long string here.  is a string of the format `X XX:X:0.0`, whereby `X` is a character and `0` an integer.

Comment: as a very quick check , could you do `nchar(rd)` (from previous Q), and exclude the rows with > X number of characters

Comment: `Z` isn't a long string, how are you planing to identify it?

Comment: One option is to use `read.delim2` with `comment.char = "Y"` to skip/ignore rows starting with `Y`. But it will not work in you case as your data got `Y` character in other field.

Comment: You can delete long lines using `sed` (from previous question), e.g. `fread("sed -e '/^.\\{100\\}./d' -e '$!N;s/\\n/ /' test.tab")` though I still don't understand how `Z` us a long line. It would be nice if you were a bit more responsive.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Sorry, offline. You are correct; it is unclear above. Z is a string of the format `X  XX:X:0.0`, whereby X is a character and `0` an integer.

Comment: @MKR I think this *is* a good way to ignore 'Z' though, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a system call in order to fix the file in place using, let's say `sed`, by a certain pattern. If you want to remove all the rows that begin with `Z` or `Y` you can simply pass a regex expression followed by `/d`

```
system("sed -i '/^[ZY]/d' test.tab")
```

The command above will remove all the rows that begin with Z or Y from you file. Then, you can run the same code I've posted in your previous question

```
library(data.table)
fread("sed '$!N;s/\\n/ /' test.tab")
#    V1   V2 V3   V4 V5   V6   V7         V8
# 1:  A 1092  - 1093  + 1X B 1093 HRDCPMRFYT
# 2:  A 1093  + 1094  - 1X B 1094 BSZSDFJRVF
# 3:  A 1094  + 1095  + 1X B 1095 SSTFCLEPVV
```

---

Data

```
text <- "Z FX:E:4.2
Y  23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M,23434M 
A   1092    -   1093    +   1X
B   1093    HRDCPMRFYT
A   1093    +   1094    -   1X
B   1094    BSZSDFJRVF
A   1094    +   1095    +   1X
B   1095    SSTFCLEPVV"

# Saving it as tab separated file on disk
write(gsub(" +", "\t", text), file = "test.tab")
```